# Replace special characters in Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using `iframe`-tag to embed Google Map to my website. Since it's a Norwegian address I have to replace characters like æ, ø, å and so on with UTF-8 hex-code which is working fine. But there are some characters which I can't seem to replace.

To replicate the issue I have this `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="googlemap" name="mapframe" width="425" height="350" 
            src="https://www.google.com/maps?z=11&amp;f=d&amp;output=embed&amp;language=nb&amp;q=Lille%2520Hunstad%25204A,8019%252BBOD%25C3%2598">
</iframe>
```

And I am using this jQuery-code to replace characters:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/** REPLACE SPECIAL CHARACTERS IN GOOGLE MAPS IFRAME SRC **/
    var googleMap = $('#googlemap');
    var src;
    src = googleMap.attr('src');
    src = encodeURI(src);
    googleMap.attr('src', src);

    src.replace('æ', '%C3%A6');
    src.replace('ø', '%C3%B8');
    src.replace('å', '%C3%A5');
    src.replace('é', '%C3%A9');
    src.replace('Æ', '%C3%86');
    src.replace('Ø', '%C3%98');
    src.replace('Å', '%C3%85');
    src.replace('É', '%C3%89'); // replacing is working to here
    src.replace('%252520', '+');
    src.replace('%25252B', '+');
    src.replace('%2525', '%');
});
```

Here you can see the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oehLcevd/9/

If you inspect the `iframe` with Dev Tools, you can see the `src`-attribute of the `iframe`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to normalized your query using [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function in JavaScript. I wonder why i had to call it twice to normalize the URL parameters but if you inspect the iFrame src now it will show your required answer. Hope someone with better knowledge can shed some light.

The first console output will show the original URL and second one will illustrate the decoded URL.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /** REPLACE SPECIAL CHARACTERS IN GOOGLE MAPS IFRAME SRC **/
  var googleMap = $('#googlemap');
  var src;
  src = googleMap.attr('src');
  console.log(googleMap.attr('src'));
  googleMap.attr('src', decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(src)));
  console.log(googleMap.attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Address: Lille Hunstad 4A, 8019 BODØ
<br>
<iframe id="googlemap" name="mapframe" width="425" height="350" src="https://www.google.com/maps?z=11&amp;f=d&amp;output=embed&amp;language=en&amp;q=Lille%2520Hunstad%25204A,8019%252BBOD%25C3%2598">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you are replacing string but not assigning back to it..

```
    src = src.replace('æ', '%C3%A6');
    src = src.replace('ø', '%C3%B8');
    src = src.replace('å', '%C3%A5');
    src = src.replace('é', '%C3%A9');
    src = src.replace('Æ', '%C3%86');
    src = src.replace('Ø', '%C3%98');
    src = src.replace('Å', '%C3%85');
    src = src.replace('É', '%C3%89');    
    src = src.replace('%252520', '+');
    src = src.replace('%25252B', '+');
    src = src.replace('%2525', '%');
```

and also replacing src variable don't mean you change your google maps iframe src. so you should put this code at the end of the replacement:

```
    googleMap.attr('src', src);
```

**EDIT**

BTW, you already used localization parameter (**language=nb**). Why u need to convert characters further? Just put the adress to query parameter, you won't need to convert it:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?z=11&amp;f=d&amp;output=embed&amp;language=nb&amp;q=Lille Hunstad 4A, 8019 BODØ
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oehLcevd/10/)